# Redux state changes back to Intital state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am creating a web app where a user chooses a restaurant on one screen and the name of the restaurant is stored and then the menu screen checks the state for the restaurant name and gets the menu items from the server for that restaurant. When I press the button in `userscreen.js` the first time, the state doesn't change but it does change the next time. However, when I check the state from `menu.js` it is still the initialized state, which is empty. How do I get the state to not change back to its original value?

Here are the files im working on:

userscreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setRestaurant } from '../actions/restaurant';

class Userscreen extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state={
        r2:'',
    };
    this.handleClick1 = this.handleClick1.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('api/rest-ratings', {
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(body =>{
        this.setState({r2: body.C})
    })
}

handleClick1(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.setRestaurant("ChopChop");
    console.log(this.props.rest)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={user_background} alt="" style= {{width: "100%", height: "auto", margin:"0auto"}}/>
            <div id="btn2" onClick={this.handleClick1}>
                Chop Chop
                <div>
                <StarRatingComponent name="ChopChop" editing={false} starCount={5} value={parseInt(this.state.r2)}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    rest: state.rest,
})

export  default connect(mapStateToProps, { setRestaurant })(Userscreen)
```

menu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setRestaurant } from '../actions/restaurant';

class Menu extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        rest1: 'abc',
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
        console.log("mine",this.state.rest1)
        console.log("store",this.props.rest)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        {this.state.rest}
        </div>
    );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    rest: state.rest
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {setRestaurant})(Menu);
```

restaurant.js

```
export const setRestaurant = (restaurant) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'SET_RESTAURANT',
        payload: restaurant
    })
}
```

restReducer.js

```
 const initialState = {
    restaurant : ''
 }

export default function(state = initialState, action ) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SET_RESTAURANT':
            return {
                ...state,
                restaurant: action.payload,
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import errorReducer from './errorReducer';
import authReducer from './authReducer';
import restReducer from './restReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    errors: errorReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
    rest: restReducer
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatch binder function should be defined as a simple action creator if it is going to be used like it is in `export default connect(mapStateToProps, {setRestaurant})(Menu);`:

```
export const setRestaurant = restaurant => ({
    type: 'SET_RESTAURANT',
    payload: restaurant
})
```

See [defining mapDispatchToProps as an object](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object)

Also note that the `mapStateToProps` function passes the returned object via the *props* (as the name suggests) so using those passed in props should be done through `this.props` (instead of `this.state`).

```
return (
    <div>{this.props.rest.restaurant}</div> 
)
```